# XMLRPC Java Android Client

Tags: android, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I downloaded the [XMLRPC client project](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) and try to initialize a connection to my XMLRPC server.

I set up a local server for testing and use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/OpenConf_Server-0.0.1/` to call the rpc.

Each time I'm calling my test method, that only return a simple string, i receive the following error message of the XMLRPC client.

What is going wrong?

```
05-22 16:08:27.503: E/OpenConfDashboardDesignActivity(759): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}methodResponse (position:START_TAG <html>@4:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@413092f8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more logging,  Mostly likely it is the path of the server that's is incorrect.

```
    } catch (final XMLRPCFault e) {
            // TODO: do something with message.contains
            Log.i(TAG, "XMLRPCFault : " +e.toString());
            String message = e.getMessage();
            if (message.contains("<html>")) {
                Log.i(TAG, MessCon" : " +e.toString());
                return null;
            }
        } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, " XMLRPCException : " +e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, " respnse : " + response);
        return response;
```